# How to print something without a new line in ruby

Tags: ruby

`puts` statement in ruby automatically adds a new line, how do I avoid it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use "puts" to the console without a line break in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080644/how-can-i-use-puts-to-the-console-without-a-line-break-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: `puts` puts an EOL, `print` doesn't. `p` does something else!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Use `print` instead.
You may want to follow it up by `STDOUT.flush`.

Comment: For your information. `STDOUT.flush` flushes any buffered data within ios to the underlying operating system. ```$STDOUT.print "no newline" $STDOUT.flush``` produce ```no newline```

Comment: Awesome, thx @Sergio :) I knew it but I always like seeing your posts hehe ~

Comment: @sidney: I'm glad my post was useful :)

Answer (score 8):

Also, you'll need to append "\r" at end of line to indicate "carriage return" and do next print at beginning of current line

Comment: Not if he's simply planning to print more at the end of the current line. He can use puts for the last print to complete the line. This is useful when printing a list of varying (yet short) length, for example.

Answer (score 7):

```
$stdout.sync = true

100.times do
    print "."
    sleep 1
end
```

["How can I use “puts” to the console without a line break in ruby on rails?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080779/657988)