# no output until script completely finishes when doing vagrant up provider=rackspace

Tags: vagrant, openstack, rackspace

i am using vagrant to spin up some servers in a rackspace  / open stack cluster.  I am using the vagrant rackspace plugin ( https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-rackspace ).

My provisioning script executes and works fine --  with one inconvenience, however:   I don't see any output from the script until the very end.  Somehow all script output seems like it is being buffered, and I do see it.. but not until the script has complete terminated.

I have a workaround which is to  'tee' the output of all the scripts i run to a file which i can look at (during provisioning) if i use the rackspace console to login.. But it would be even better if the output scrolled by immediately as it was produced, rather than being buffered and dumped out at the end.

[ note - i also filed a bug with the developer, and i will update this thread if i get an answer there.   note2:  i tried this with :keep_color => true     and without that parameter..  same result: no output until the end).

To reproduce, please use your rackspace credentials instead of the dummy ones below. Then run 
*vagrant up provider=rackspace*.     You will see all of the output appear at once (rather then  seeing the message "sleeping 40 secs", followed by  a delay, then another message.)

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

             config.vm.box = "dummy"
             config.ssh.pty = true          # work around issue where sudo requires tty


            config.vm.provision :shell,
              :keep_color => true,
              :inline=> ' ( echo sleeping 40 secs ; sleep 40 ; echo sleep again for 40 secs ; sleep 40 ) | tee /tmp/out'


             config.ssh.private_key_path = "./id_rsa"

             config.vm.provider :rackspace do |rs|
                rs.username        = "bozo"
                rs.api_key         = "the-clown"
                rs.flavor          = /1 GB Performance/
                rs.image           = "bfa5783c-e40e-4668-adc1-feb0ae3d7a46"

                rs.public_key_path = "./id_rsa.pub"
                rs.rackspace_region = :dfw
             end

    end
```

Comment: I have something same with inline script execution.

Comment: I have the same issue. What I end up doing is hitting enter to update the output, this seems to load in the buffered console text immediately.I would love to know how to fix this too. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Rackspace Account but maybe is the same Problem as:

[How can I use "puts" to the console without a line break in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080644/how-can-i-use-puts-to-the-console-without-a-line-break-in-ruby-on-rails)

Try adding this to your Vagrantfile:

```
$stdout.sync = true
$stderr.sync = true
```

Comment: Thanks. i am on another project now, so it might be a while before i can try. appreciate the suggestion though.